# Android GPS Always Returns Same Location

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the user's location within Android, the code below works however it always returns the same location no matter what I do. I've tested out in the middle of an empty parking lot to ensure the GPS is locked on, and it is. Google maps also shows my location correctly. Is there something wrong with the code below?

```
public class LocationTestActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener
{   
private Location myLoc;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
    myLong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longi);
    myLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat);
    myRefreshed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);

    mgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    timesChanged++;
    myRefreshed.setText("Refreshed: " + timesChanged);
    myLong.setText("Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
    myLat.setText("Latitude: " + location.getLatitude());
}
}
```

I'd like to add that I can pass in a location using the emulator with no problem. I also removed the other needed methods required by LocationListener for clarity. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? I have the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that onLocationChanged() is actually getting called. If your GPS has locked before then there is a chance that onLocationChanged won't get fired at all because the phone thinks that you haven't really moved. Therefore it is not a good practice to rely only on requestLocationUpdates() to get your current location.

In general here is what you should do to get your position:

1. You should use getLastKnownLocation() first to try locating your current location based on last known position.
2. Check if the location retrieved from step #1 is within reasonable time (not too old) by calling getTime() in the location and comparing with the current time
3. If this last known position is considered old (I normally use 5-10 minutes depending on the context of the app) then you start requestLocationUpdates() with specific distance (the app should make assumption that the user has moved within the specified limit of last known position)
4. Implement the onLocationChanged() as desired

Another note, I notice you are only using GPS, there is a lot of situation where GPS cannot lock and therefore never call onLocationChange(), your code should take account of that and checking Network based triangulation in the case onLocationChange() is not called within specified time

Comment: I use timesChanged++; to determine if it fires, it does. GPS does get locked on as I didn't post some code that shows a text warning saying it's disabled etc... I bumped the time in between to 15000 to give it time, still no change in location. As posted below I drove a few miles away and lat/long was exactly the same as home. I realize there are checks I should be doing however lat/long doesn't change for any location provider or anything I do. While testing all this, google maps got my location correct while using GPS so I don't think my phone is at fault here.

Comment: Are you saying location variable in public void onLocationChanged(Location location) still pointing to the same location even though the onLocationChanged is called? Or are you saying myLoc variable that you declare remains the same? I've never seen the first case. If it's the second case, I don't see you set this.myloc = location in onLocationChanged. I assume you intend to use myLoc.

Comment: You're right, the intention is to eventually to use myLoc, however I'm saying the first case is what is going on. Everything is running/firing correctly but the location never updates. If I use the emulator and not my phone, the code reflects the location I pass in. I'm starting to think my phone is at fault - I've even changed roms.

Comment: Ok, one more possibility. Are you enabling mock location on your phone settings? The setting is known to override the GPS especially if you combine it with other app that could set your location on the phone (such as MyFakeLocation).

Comment: No, it's off. However I tried messing with that setting before posting here. I downloaded an app from the market to display lat/long coords of my phone and it outputs exactly the same thing as the code I've posted. I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting last location fix

```
Location loc =  mgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

and give some time/distance between each location service request

```
 mgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
```

And I hope you have enough patience to wait until your device retrieves the location and `onLocationChanged()` is triggered ;) Joking.

Comment: The last location returns exactly what I'm getting when running the above code. The only difference in location I get is +-0.00100 in both lat and long. I just drove ~5 miles away and still got the same location as home.

Comment: Specify as i suggested above. And check if the location updates every X minutes/seconds/milliseconds

Comment: Sorry - I meant to say I did try this and it updates about once a second. The location does update, but as I stated in the comment above, it's a minuscule change.

Comment: Did you have the solution? I have the same problem here. :(

If I use Google Maps and then try my application again, everything works again.

I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: You need to request again location updates, using the same procedure whenever onResume is called (in your case, when the app is resumed, not being run for "first time")

Answer (score 0):

please check your manifest file whether have you added those permission or not.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```

One more thing.Where did you call "removeUpdates()"?

Comment: Yes those permissions are added, my understanding is that the code I wrote won't run without them. I don't call removeUpdates() as I don't want them removed. Just for giggles I tried removing the updates and starting them again, still get no change in location no matter how far I move.